# Joining values of rows in the column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the tibble that looks like this, with name of the columns:

```
  A      B      C      D
<char> <char> <char> <char>
  Aa     Bb     C      D 
  Aa     Bb     C      D
```

I want to get this:

```
  A      B      C      D
<char> <char> <char> <char>
 AaAa   BbBb    C      D
```

So, in case the string is exactly the same in all rows, I would like to preserve only this one value. If they are different - join them together into one string.

Comment: Row 2 and Row 3 are identical(). Even tough row 1 is distinct() from them. I think you might want to revise your desired output.

Comment: By the first row I meant name of the columns - sorry for misleading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you even want this behavior, but you can achieve this with this code:

```
x=read.table(header = T, text="
A  B  C D
Aa Bb C D 
Aa Bb C D")
x %>% 
  group_by(C, D) %>% 
  summarise_at(c("A","B"), ~paste(.x, collapse=""))
```

Basically, you group by your "fixed" columns and you collapse at A and B using paste.

This is to get your expected output. If I refer to you text though, it seems more like this:

```
x=read.table(header = T, text="
A  B  C D
Aa Ba C D 
Aa Ba C D 
Aa Bb C D")
x %>% 
  group_by(C, D) %>% 
  summarise_at(c("A","B"), ~{
    if(length(levels(factor(.x)))==1) .x[1] else paste(unique(.x), collapse="")
  })
```

If there is only one value in the column, you output this value, else you output the concatenation of all unique values.

> ```
> # A tibble: 1 x 4
> # Groups:   C [1]
>   C     D     A     B    
>   <fct> <fct> <fct> <chr>
> 1 C     D     Aa    BaBb
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be, you are looking for this?

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tribble(
    ~A, ~B, ~C, ~D,
    "Aa", "Bb", "C", "D", 
    "Aa", "Bb", "C", "D",
)

df %>% # take the dataframe
    group_by_all() %>% # group it by all columns (i.e. unique combinations)
    slice(1) # and get the first row in each group

  A     B     C     D    
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 Aa    Bb    C     D
```